# Switch Maven repository 'cache(http://cache)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols

Tags: android, jitpack, android-maven-plugin, buildsrc

I'm using a `buildSrc` module in my Android library project, and a `jitpack` build at `jitci.com` fails with the error message shown below. However, locally, the project builds and runs on my phone fine, and a `jitpack` build of the latest project release at the `jitpack.io` website builds fine. I am also able to use that successful build in a separate Android project as a dependency. Why does the build fail at `jitci.com` only, with that error message? I'm not using the maven repository `cache(http://cache)` anywhere in my project, and I'm not using any insecure HTTP connections for repositories anywhere in my project.

**settings.gradle file**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "ComposeComponents"
include ':app'
include ':compose-components'
```

**build.gradle file @ buildSrc module**

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**jitpack build exception error message @ jitci.com**

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.
63. > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':buildSrc:classpath'.
64. > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. 
Switch Maven repository 'cache(http://cache)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
```